# Maximum number of columns in view

Tags: mysql

There is a (complex) maximum number of columns in a table in mySQL.

But what about a maximum number of columns in a view?

I mean, a view might be a join of numerous tables. Will there be a maximum of the total number of columns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of question is (nearly) always symptomatic of an underlying flaw in design and/or approach towards data display.

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree: "nearly always"...:-) However, we have some very strong reasons. We have some "crazy" long questionnaires. So the flaw in design is not the datamodel but the business logic.

Comment: Not that it's any of my business but I'm entirely unconvinced.

Comment: @Strawberry, you are most welcome to make suggestions. We have a few questionnaires with 300-500 questions. Those questionnaires are combined with other questionnaires (less than 50 questions). We need to load full records. How will you propose to design this?

Comment: Without further knowledge of your 'very strong reasons', I can't really say. But the length of a given questionnaire cannot be relevant.

Comment: @Strawberry, I don't understand how the length of a given questionnaire cannot be relevant? If we split up the questionnaire into several tables and/or not joining them in a view or when doing the select (same same), then we will have to query the database several times which will significantly slow down the user experience. The "very strong reasons" are the combination of huge questionnaires and the desire to make a nice user experience, and also don't want to complicate the application more than necessary. Still open to your suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL 5.7 reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html), there is a maximum of 4096 columns per table. I am not sure if this is also the case for queries though I would assume so and I also don't think that you would practically every have a database table or search query with over that amount.

Comment: Case is that in practical terms the maximum number of columns in a table is much less than 4096. The actual maximum depends on length and datatype of the columns involved. Is this the same with views? Or?

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm I suspect the only way you'll get a definitive answer is if you try it yourself with some test tables and see what happens. In any case, even a view with that many columns is very likely a symptom of a horrible database design.

Comment: ok. I will try it then. I understand your point on "terrible" database model :-) But we have some very valid reasons for this design. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, a questionnaire table might look like this:

```
questionnaire_id, question_no, question
               1            1  What is your name?
               1            2  Where do you live?
               1            3  What is your favourite colour?
               2            1  What is the capital of France?
               2            2  Who wrote Beethoven's Fifth?
               2            3  When was the Great Fire of London?
```

So, there we have two questionnaires (of potentially unlimited length) occupying exactly 3 columns in a table.

Any remaining 'user-experience' issues would properly be handled in application code.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but try make statistics (tabulations) on such data structure :-)

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm I anticipate that that would be very easy indeed.

Comment: making a flat structure when making statistics will both complicate the tabulations and make it very slow. Somehow you fight the logic of a relational database. Also the number of rows will become very high creating performance issues all the way down the road. I am very familiar with this approach, but it is surely not the path to go.

Comment: You are most assuredly mistaken. *I* fight the logic of a relational database? How does *that* work!!?! RDBMSs love rows and hate columns. Oh, and to clarify a technical point it's *your* design that's *flat*, not mine.

Comment: with respect, but you should try it then. I have tried this approach. If you go down that path you will have to make a really complex application preprocessing the data and making subtables for the tabulations. What you are doing is to make a record into a collection of rows, which makes (cross) tabulation very complex as it will basically take the tabulation out of the database itself and into some kind of applicational procedure, and then maybe storing the result into a subtable for user selections. Turning a small issue into a big issue :-) Anyway, thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: I have no idea what you're going on about. You're certainly mistaken (in terms of which process is more complex), but I fear it would be unfruitful to attempt to dissuade you of your fantasies. So, good luck.

Comment: you should really try make tabulations on a flat database model. Your approach is known as the Big Bear. You'll only need one table for all your applications combined, and you'll disable all kind of database structure and logic. It will surely not perform, and you will need to make a huge application to reinstall the structure on a logical level. But true if you only want to reduce the number of columns, it will work.. :-) Again, thanks for taking your time.